# Treeview Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

When we delete any row from treeview by .delete of treeview but the indexes of other rows donot autoupdate like if i have three rows in treeview I delete the first row, the others rows will adjust the position but the index remain same.
I want that when i delete any row others row indexes updates automatically

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk
win = Tk()
def deleterow(user):
        b = treeview.selection()
        rnum = b[0][3]
        print(rnum)
        for item in b:
               treeview.delete(item)
treeview=ttk.Treeview(win,columns=("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"),show="headings",height=16)
treeview.column("# 1",width=40,anchor=CENTER)
treeview.heading("# 1",text="Pr Id")
treeview.column("# 2",width=120,anchor=CENTER)
treeview.heading("# 2",text="Name")
treeview.column("# 3",width=90,anchor=CENTER)
treeview.heading("# 3",text="Barcode")
treeview.column("# 4",width=90,anchor=CENTER)
treeview.heading("# 4",text="Price")
treeview.column("# 5",width=90,anchor=CENTER)
treeview.heading("# 5",text="Qantity")
treeview.insert("",0,values=("hi","11","33"))
treeview.insert("",1,values=("hi1","112","332"))
treeview.insert("",2,values=("hi4","114","334"))
treeview.insert("",3,values=("hi4","11","33"))
treeview.grid(row=1,column=0)

closebutton=Button(win,text="del",width=7,height=2)
closebutton.grid(row=1,column=1)
closebutton.bind("<Button>",deleterow)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is "Indexes" here?

Comment: Aashan < I tried you code and it seems to be doing what you have programmed it for. If you could tell us what "Indexes" is because it is not in your code. Do you mean  this? treeview.insert("",index=0,values=("hi","11","33"))

Comment: You can see I have made a variable b: which is equal to selection and in rnum I am storing the value of third number of that string which will be 1 for if I select first row and 2 if I select second now when if i delete a certain row and then select a row it will give me the previous  value not updated one as if I delete first row the second row will come at the position of first row but its rnum value will remain 2 I want that it should be updated to 1

Comment: `b` is a tuple of *"row IDs"* created by `Treeview` internally if you did not assign one via `iid` option of `insert()`.  They are not *indexes*.  Also using `rnum = b[0][3]` to get the row index works only for index below 10, ie `I001` to `I009`.  Use `treeview.index(b[0])` instead.

Comment: acw1668
ok but how can I get the index of specific row during run time

Comment: @AashanKhan As I said use `treeview.index(row_id)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes yes Thank you so much for your help  problem is solved by your help